# start at the same hour every day

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Hello in xAxis I need to function getTime () (for example) start every day at 0:00 am, or also at 06:00 am, or also at 12:00 pm or also at 18:00 pm

```
xAxis: { categories: ["+6","+9","+12","+15","+18","+21","+24","+27","+30","+33","+36","+39","+42","+45","+48","+51","+54","+57","+60","+63","+66","+69","+72","+75","+78","+81","+84","+87","+90","+93","+96","+99","+102","+105","+108","+111","+114","+117","+120","+123",+"126","+129","+132","+135","+138","+141","+144","+147","+150","+153","+156","+159","+162","+165","+168","+171","+174","+177","+180","+183","+186","+189","+192"],
```

+6 Always starts at 00:00 hours, 6:00 hours to 12:00 hours and 18:00 hours

So I need to know the function getTime () starts at a specific time every day for four different graphics

Thanks

Comment: Could you show some mockup how should this look like? In Highcharts you can set [pointStart](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.pointStart) and [pointInterval](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.pointInterval).

Comment: Thanks:

I agree, but I need dynamic pointstar (start at 12.00 am today, tomorrow ............ start at 12.00 am every day should begin at 12.00 am) http://jsfiddle.net/raposu/JtMDj/  but I can not make it work

Comment: How `pointStart` could be dynamic? Do you mean each point should be at '12:00:00:000 AM' ? In that case, take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/JtMDj/2/

Comment: P E R F E C T ,  :-) I greatly appreciate the effort, my explanations are never too good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/JtMDj/2/

Need to setup pointStart and pointInterval in that way:

```
var date = new Date();
date.setHours(12);
date.setMinutes(0);
date.setSeconds(0);
date.setMilliseconds(0);


var ts = Math.round(date / 1000);
var tsNoon = ts;

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: {
            day: '%e of %b'
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
        pointStart: tsNoon * 1000, // highcharts asks for miliseconds
        pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 // one day
    }]
});
```